# Email File to Sharepoint Calendar Event

Tags: calendar, sharepoint-email

Is there a way to email a file to an event on a sharepoint calendar?

I have a Team Calendar that I would like to email attachments to.

Comment: Is .NET code an option?

Comment: That may be option. However not cost effective at this time. But thanks for the response.

Comment: Then no, there isn't a way to do this OOTB

Answer (score 0):

Afraid not - the function to upload files via email only exists for Libraries, not Lists.

If you go to the settings and don't see an 'Incoming email for this library' link when the Incoming Email feature/service is active, it doesn't exist for that object.